# R rmarkdown::render adjusting breaking point / text wrap

Tags: r, markdown, render, r-markdown

I am trying to set the breaking point / text wrap for my automatically generated .html document..

My tries so far:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(collapse = F)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff = 6000),tidy = FALSE, out.width = 6000)
options(max.print = 2000)
options(width = 5000)
rmarkdown::render(codeDir %p% "/correlations/cor_motivation_motivation.R", output_dir = exportDir, output_file = "cor_motivation_motivation.html")
```

None of the options I tried seems to affect the output...I am printing pretty big tables with 21 x 21 elements - instead of breaking them into multiple lines (see image) I would like to enable horizontal scrolling or at least fill 100% of the screen:
[image]

Comment: Changing options()$width changes the html output for me.

Comment: how? If I `options()$width` R returns: `[1] 5000` but I still have the same breaking point?

Comment: I'm not sure how it works. In working with tables, I noticed that I could get distinct html outputs when I changed the options()$width value.